# How to refresh user control in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net

I have user control having `Gridview` inside it on parent page,on the same form one popup window gets open for document upload.

When I upload the document from pop window on attach button,it should get reflected to `gridview` of parent page.

I want to refresh my user control on attach button of pop window.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to refresh your user control to Refresh the data of your grid view, then simply call your grid view bind function here again just after uploading new documents.